# How deeply nested threads are managed in multi-threaded architecture

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, scheduler

I just have a quick question. Say you start a program, then create 5 threads, then each of those create 5 threads, then each of those create 5 threads. Say they are each doing a variety of different activities, that is, they aren't just clones of simple processes running in parallel or something. They are context-specific processes that are running.

The question is if you need a global/central manager for all these threads, or if it can/should be done differently.

So you have something like:

```
|------------ 1
    |________ 1.1
    |   |____ 1.1.1
    |   |____ 1.1.2
    |   |____ 1.1.3
    |   |____ 1.1.4
    |   |____ 1.1.5
    |
    |________ 1.2
    |   |____ 1.2.1
    |   |____ 1.2.2
    |   |____ 1.2.3
    |   |____ 1.2.4
    |   |____ 1.2.5
    |
    |________ 1.3
    |   |____ 1.3.1
    |   |____ 1.3.2
    |   |____ 1.3.3
    |   |____ 1.3.4
    |   |____ 1.3.5
    |
    | ...
    |________ 1.5
        |____ 1.5.1
         ...
```

So in this diagram there are about 31 processes, but if you add another layer of 5 nested you get a lot more.

What I'm wondering is generally *who* is managing the processes. It seems that you could have it multiple different ways. In one way you could have the top-level `1` "main" process govern all the nested and deeply nested children. This would mean there is one "global" manager layer for all processes. This seems like it would make it easier in terms of scheduling / prioritizing what process gets access to resources, because there is a central manager. At the same time, however, it lacks modularity and doesn't act like a real-world multi-process thingy.

But you could perhaps have it a different way. You could have each parent node only manage its direct descendents. This makes sense from a purity standpoint, as each process would only be responsible for managing its children. This is sort of how hierarchically managed organizations/businesses work. But I quickly get confused in thinking how you would go about dealing with the scheduling problems on a sequential architecture. I haven't ever implemented this, so I'm not sure how hard it is, but it seems hard at first. You could run into the situation where `1.3.5` was using a bunch of resources, but `1.1.1` really needed to get some processing done, and `1.2` at the high level wanted to get some work done too. So some central manager (it seems like) would have to coordinate message passing between these processes to help them get on schedule with each other. But then we're right back to the first situation of a global central manager. So I don't know how to avoid this.

A third approach might be where every process manages itself. They have a central sort of "registry" type thing where they can mark their progress, and they all act in a certain fair way regarding that "contract". In this way there's not really a central manager so much as a decentralized network. But this also quickly seems to become complicated when trying to imagine how you would resolve complex conflict chains/graphs during scheduling and prioritization. I get overwhelmed by it.

So I'm wondering what the general approach is to this problem. If it is (1) global central manager, (2) parent/child management, or (3) decentralized registry / self-management, or (4) another thing besides these approaches. In knowing this it would become clearer how to implement multiple threads on a sequential architecture such as in JavaScript, for learning exercise. You would do 1, 2, or 3 and could have threads that each get the opportunity to do processing. I just can't tell if it requires a central manager or not, and so am wondering what the *typical* approach is in a robust system, and what the *best* approach(es) is/are roughly speaking.

Comment: Interesting question, but it can only be answered by the operations system developers. Probably, it is handled differently in "normal" operating systems, and real-time operating systems.